# Meaning of "sex on the legs"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I'm currently listening to *Casual Vacancy* and heard an idiom/expression *sex on the legs* in this book. Is it some widely used expression or is context required to understand its meaning?

Answer (score 7):

I believe the expression is 'sex on legs' and refers to a person's sexual attractiveness.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sex_on_legs
Also http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sex_on_a_stick

Comment: There is also a track by Queen called _Sex on two legs_ with similar meaning.

Comment: Not necessarily sexual attractiveness. It can refer to the user's [claimed] sexual prowess or experience.

Comment: Hmmm. You're all right, I suppose, but, I'll confess: The first thing I thought of was the quote from Rocky's manager in the first _Rocky_ movie: ["Women weaken legs!"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075148/quotes)

Comment: Just realized it was called _death on two legs_. Now would that be considered a Freudian slip?